# Is my translation of “I’m talking about the software. It’s slow in translating but precise.” grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaire, traduction

Is my translation of “I’m talking about the software. It’s slow in translating but precise.” grammatically correct?

Because « **être lent(e) à** » égale “**to be slow in ...-ing**”, I reached

« Je parle du logiciel. C’est lente à traduire mais précis. »

Est-ce correct ?

If it’s incorrect, I would really like to know why because I don’t understand why it would be incorrect grammatically as I used the above template correctly. :(

Also, please let me know if this type of question is not allowed.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are two mistakes in :

> C'est lente à traduire mais précis.

First, you are talking about a specific software, not generic ones so you should use : *il est...*

Second, there is a agreement discrepancy, *lente* is feminine but *logiciel* is masculine.

The expected sentence is then:

> Je parle du logiciel. Il est lent à traduire mais précis.

Comment: @jiliagre Merci !  But what if you are speaking casually. Can you use « C’est » au lieu de « Il est » in this scenario?

Comment: Not really. *C'est lent à traduire* apply to something generic: [But c’est has an additional use: it can be followed by an adjective that describes the general sense of an inanimate noun, something unspecific, an abstraction (situation, opinion, feeling). This adjective is always masculine.](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/cest-vs-il-est/)

Comment: https://www.lawlessfrench.com/expressions/cest/ : “Only c’est can be used in these constructions:” ... “2) Adjectives that describe either something already mentioned or a general idea.”

Comment: *Tu penses quoi de la traduction avec ce logiciel ? C'est lent !*

Comment: Lol, this is really embarrassing mais I don’t understand what you said. 

Comment: I gave you an example of *c'est* describing something already mentioned: "What do you think about the translation performed by this program? It's slow!"

Comment: Just wondering here if "il est lent à traduire" might not sound like "I am trying to translate it from Java to C# and this is a slow process". Wouldn't something along the line "Il est lent lorsqu'il traduit mais est précis" clear that out?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I though about it too but ruled it out considering this meaning is more the one of *il est **long** à traduire*. Your alternative suggestion avoids *être lent à* while I guess the OP goal was to use it. I'm not sure *précis* is the best adjective for a translation. Here is how I would have translated the sentence: *Je parle du logiciel. Il n'est pas rapide, mais ses traductions sont (très) justes*.

Comment: @jlliagre … cette dernière proposition est plus aboutie, certainement pas celle d’un robot :-)